# A question regarding my proof

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I've modified the proof. I request you to verify this proof.

CLAIM: If $X$ is a compact metric space and $f$ is continuous on $X$, then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$.

PROOF: If $f$ is not uniformly continuous on $X$, then there is a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in X such that $(f(x_n))$ is not Cauchy. Since $X$ is compact(hence complete)  $(x_n)$ converges to some point in $X$.  Since $f$ is continuous, $(f(x_{n}))$ converges. But this would imply that $(f(x_n))$  is Cauchy which is a contradiction.

Comment: How does the convergence of $\big( f(x_{n_k}) \big)$ imply the convergence of $\big( f(x_n) \big)$? Remember, your assumption was that $\big( f(x_n) \big)$ was not Cauchy.

Comment: What you're showing is that $f$ is Cauchy-continuous. In general metric spaces, this is not equivalent to uniform continuity, but if the domain is totally bounded (which compact spaces always are), then they are equivalent.

Comment: You may want to try using the finite-subcover-property of compacts directly

Comment: I've modified the proof.

Comment: The 1st sentence of your proof is a mistake. If $X$ is ANY metric space, then $f:X\to \Bbb R$ is continuous iff $(f(x_n))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $f(x)$ whenever $(x_n)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $x.$  . For example if $X=\Bbb R$ with the usual metric, and $f=id_X$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen.  Good hint................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not uniformly convergent, there is some $\varepsilon >0$ such that for all $\delta =\frac1n>0$ there are $x_n, x'_n \in X$ such that $d(x_n, x'_n) < \frac1n$ and $d(f(x(\delta)), f(x'(\delta)) \ge \varepsilon$.

Then by (sequential) compactness of $X$, there are $x_0, x'_0 \in X$ and a series of indices $n_k$ such that $x_{n_k} \to x_0, x'_{n_k} \to x'_0 $ as $k \to \infty$.

As $d(x_{n_k}, x'_{n_k}) < \frac{1}{n_k}$ we see that in fact $x_0 = x'_0$ and then we have a contradiction with continuity of $f$ at $x_0$, as $d(f(x_{n_k}), f(x'_{n_k})) \ge \varepsilon$.